# "ELB health is failing or not available for all instances" + "Request timed out" on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying for two days to get rid of this error. It also often says "100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx". I have been reading about troubleshooting from here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-fix-failing-health-checks-alb/ but nothing is working. I have tried changing the health check path from '/' to '/healthCheck' as that has worked for some other people.

**INFO:**

I am using an application load balancer so that I can use HTTPS. I am using t3.micro although I have tried t3.small and t3.medium.

Here are my load balancer settings in the configuration part of console:
[image: hi]

My security group for the instance has the same two inbound rules at source 0.0.0.0/0 and outbounds all traffic to 0.0.0.0/0.

And here is some target group info:

[image: hello]

Where is the best place to look for this error?

Comment: Does your website work if: (1) you access it directly through the instnace - not using ELB, just IP of an instance? (2) if not, does it work when you log in to the instance, and `curl` it from the inside?

Comment: @Marcin (1) does not load the website, and I don't really understand what you mean by log into the instance and curl it from the inside

Comment: Does your application work? The first thing to check is to identify whether the issue is with your ALB or the application it self.

Comment: @Marcin The application does not work, however it did before, as I have been changing things bit by bit. I thought that this error was for sure with my ALB settings though, since it's not getting a health check?

Comment: If app is not working, then have to fix it first. Do EB logs show any errors?

Comment: @Marcin The main error I have been getting in the logs is "Script timed out before returning headers: application.py" which after looking up, seemed to be fixed with a .config file in the .ebextensions folder, but yet I haven't gotten it to go away. I am pretty sure I have gotten this error in the logs without getting this request timed out health error though

Comment: Can you login to the instance using ssh and inspect from the inside if the app is working, does it timeout as well?

Comment: @Marcin I honestly think I'm just gonna start over with a new environment I've already messed with the settings in this one enough that I'm not sure how it started. Thanks for all the help though !

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I will make an answer if you don't mind for future reference.

Comment: You don't need to use a load balancer just to use HTTPS. Configure HTTPS within the .ebextensions/https-instance.config.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.

The cause of the issue is undetermined. Thus it was decided to make **new EB environment** in an effort to address the problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, not sure yet how prevalent it will be but it happened to me twice after a number of broken deploys during testing.  I even created a specific endpoint to return `200` without luck.  It seems to be more of a load balancer problem than an instance problem.  A new environment for me cleared up the problem.